# Nested procedures in procedures

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Is it possible to create a procedure in SQL Server, in which another procedure can be passed as a parameter for execution?
Analogue of generic methods.

For example:

```sql
ALTER PROCEDURE [db].[myProc]
...
 @externalProc              PROCEDURE?    
...
 
BEGIN

  DECLARE 2 datetime variables: start/end
  SET start = GETDATE()
  EXEC @externalProc
  SET end = GETDATE()
//Other work with the received data

END
```

The bottom line is that I want to create 1 generic procedure that will do the same for many other procedures.

Comment: No. Parameters must be a `TYPE`, such as `varchar`, `datetime` or a user defined `table` type, not an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass the procedure name as the parameter for the wrapper stored procedure and execute it dynamically. But, I would suggest avoiding this kind of dynamic procedure execution, as it can lead to many issues. Some of them:

- we don't know what is the logic of the parameter procedure content
- It can lead to SQL injection
- It can lead to security issues

I am giving sample code for test case of how this can be done. I have not considered SQL injection and other things. I am just putting to show that it is possible.

```
-- stored procedure to call
create procedure dbo.test
as
select 1

-- Wrapper stored procedure
create procedure dbo.uber_proc
@procname VARCHAR(128)
as
begin
DECLARE @sql_stmt NVARCHAR(256) = 'EXEC ' + @procname
EXEC(@sql_stmt)
end

-- Executing wrapper stored procedure
EXEC dbo.uber_proc 'dbo.test'
```

**update**
thanks to @Iptr, we can also create the wrapper stored procedure as given below:

```sql
CREATE procedure dbo.uber_proc
@procname VARCHAR(128)
as
begin
  EXEC @procname
end
```

Comment: dynamic sql is not needed  ..instead of exec(@sql) just execute exec @procname (notice there are no parentheses after exec)

Comment: @Iptr, I have updated my answer. I did not know that it is possible that way. thanks for enlightening me.